# C# Internet Explorer and stripping HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, strip-tags

Is there any way to open Internet Explorer process from C#, send html content to this browser and capture 'displayed' content?

I am aware of other html stripping methods (e.g. HtmlAgilityPack) but I would like to explore the above avenue.

Thanks, 
LG

Comment: Perfectly valid question IMO.

Comment: You can use `WebBrowser` control. `webBrowser.DocumentText=<html>....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WebBrowser control, which exists for both WinForms and WPF, to host IE in your application. You can then set the control's Source to your HTML, wait for the content to load (using the LayoutUpdated event, not the Loaded event, which is raised when the HTML is finished downloading, not necessarily arranged and all dynamic JS run), then access the Document property to get the HTML.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Could you tell me how can I pull visible content from the Document property? thanks

Comment: The Document property is defined as `object` in WPF, but it's actually a wrapper around a COM IHTMLDocument object. Step into it in the debugger, you'll see it has useful properties like `body`, which contains an HTMLBodyClass object, which in turn has an `innerHTML` property, containing the HTML shown (after javascript), or `innerText`, which contains just the text, without the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<LinkItem> getListOfLinksFromPage(string webpage)
    {
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        List<LinkItem> list = new List<LinkItem>();
        try
        {
            string s = w.DownloadString(webpage);

            foreach (LinkItem i in LinkFinder.Find(s))
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(i);
                //richTextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString() + "\n");
                list.Add(i);
            }
            listTest = list;
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return list;
        }

    }

    public struct LinkItem
    {
        public string Href;
        public string Text;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Href;
        }
    }

    static class LinkFinder
    {
        public static List<LinkItem> Find(string file)
        {
            List<LinkItem> list = new List<LinkItem>();

            // 1.
            // Find all matches in file.
            MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            // 2.
            // Loop over each match.
            foreach (Match m in m1)
            {
                string value = m.Groups[1].Value;
                LinkItem i = new LinkItem();

                // 3.
                // Get href attribute.
                Match m2 = Regex.Match(value, @"href=\""(.*?)\""",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if (m2.Success)
                {
                    i.Href = m2.Groups[1].Value;
                }

                // 4.
                // Remove inner tags from text.
                string t = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s*<.*?>\s*", "",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
                i.Text = t;

                list.Add(i);
            }

            return list;

        }
    }
```

Someone else created the regular expressions so i can not take credit for that, but the above code will open a webclient object to the passed in webpage and use regular expressions to find all of the childLinks for that page.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you simply wanted to "grab" all of that HTML content and save it to a file, you could simply save the string "s" created in the line "string s = w.DownloadString(webpage);" to a File.